# Concrete description of lift in Arens-Eells space

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, mg.metric-geometry, geometric-measure-theory

Let $X$ be a compact pointed metric subspace of the $d$-dimensional Euclidean space $(\mathbb{R}^d,d_E)$ and let $AE(X)$ denote its Arens-Eells space.  Then a result of [Nik Weaver](https://www.researchgate.net/scientific-contributions/9128689_Nik_Weaver) shows that for every Lipschitz map $f:X\rightarrow E$ into a separable Banach space, there exists a unique continuous linear extension $F:AE(X)\rightarrow E$ satisfying
$$
F\circ \delta = f,
$$
where $\delta$ is the canonical isometric embedding of $X$ in $AE(X)$.  *(See [Nik's book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07CWSG9YP) for more details).*

**Question:**

---

Is there a *concrete* description of what $F$ is or how to explicitly construct it?  I would like to use it for computations...

Comment: Typo in your title (mis-spelling or autocorrect of Eells'sname).

Comment: Thanks Yemon, for some reason I find this spelling particularly difficult to remember...

Comment: And yes, the extension which you mention can be described explicitly. (I am not sure if Nik was the first to state this result explicitly, isn't it already in the work of Arens and Eells?)

Comment: In fact, have you tried looking up the original paper of Arens and Eells? Typing Arens-Eells space into a search engine seems to quickly find https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.pjm/1103043959 which is open-access

Comment: @YemonChoi: where do you see this result in their paper?  I thought it was new when I proved it.

Comment: @YemonChoi  Thanks for the link to the paper.

Comment: @NikWeaver oops, you're right; I stand corrected. I admit I can never remember the chronology, because I first saw the extension property of the A-E space (with a different name) in a talk of Godefroy, on his work with Kalton on "Lipschitz-free spaces" - but I guess your result predates this?

Comment: @YemonChoi yes, Godefroy and Kalton's paper was 2003 and my book was 1999 (also they only state the result for $X$ a Banach space).

Comment: @NikWeaver Yes I also noticed that Nik's results is more general then the Kalton paper which is only for Banach spaces.

Comment: @NikWeaver At the risk of adding on to the list of irrelevant references: some variant of the universal property of $AE(X)$ also seems to have been considered in Sec 3.8 of Joe Flood's thesis [Free topological vector spaces](http://pldml.icm.edu.pl/pldml/element/bwmeta1.element.zamlynska-0bb07cd8-2d9d-4e2a-a1db-7063e37edbcf/c/rm22101.pdf).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$AE(X)$ is the completion of the space of "molecules", i.e., the finitely supported functions $m: X \to \mathbb{R}$ which satisfy $\sum_{p \in X}m(p) = 0$. The extension $F$ of $f: X \to E$ satisfies $F(m) = \sum_{p \in X} m(p)f(p)$. (BTW $E$ need not be separable.)

Comment: Oh, so in this version you embed $X$ not via the point-evaluation map but through the map $x \mapsto m_{xe}$ (where in your notation e is the base-point...so $F(m_p)=(1_p-1_e)f(p)$...interesting)?  

Is there a known description when using the description of $AE(X)$ found at the beginning of section 1 of this paper:
https://arxiv.org/pdf/1505.07209.pdf

Comment: Well, in that paper they construct $AE(X)$ as the closed span of the point evaluations $\delta_p$ in $({\rm Lip}(X))^*$. In this case you would set $F(\delta_p) = f(p)$ and extend linearly.

Comment: (I notice that they refer to my theorem as "folklore".)

Comment: The result quoted in the above-mentioned article as folklore had appeared in print in 1976 (and quite probably earlier).

Comment: Sorry, 1981 (in preprint form, 1978).

Comment: @user131781 what is the reference?

Comment: SLN vol. 843, 217-246

Comment: I give up, what is SLN? Is there an author and title? You refer to a 30 page paper, can you give a specific reference in the paper?

Comment: @NikWeaver I believe that user131781 is referring to this paper:
https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2FBFb0089276
and "SLN" is an abbreviation for "Springer LNM".

Comment: @RobertFurber thank you! I see something pretty close to my result in Section 1, though it is only stated for metric spaces with radius $\leq 1$.  So ...

Answer (score 2):

This has already been answered but I would like to add some points which I hope might be of interest.  The clearest expression is, in my opinion, in the general setting of a complete metric space $M$ with a base point $x_0$ and radius $1$.  One then defines the Banach space $F$ consisting of the Lipschitz functions which respect the base, i.e., map $x_0$ onto $0$, with the natural norm. Then one can embed the metric space isometrically into a Banach space $E$ with the universal property that every Lipschitz map on $M$ into a Banach space $G$ which respects the base lifts to a unique linear operator on $E$ with the same norm. If one takes $G$ to be one-dimensional, then one sees that the dual of $E$ is the space of Lipschitz functions above.  Now the unit ball of the latter has a natural compact topology (pointwise or uniform convergence) and so, by standard duality theory, is a dual space. One can then turn this reasoning on its head and define $E$ to be its predual.

One can see this more clearly if one uses a little terminology from category theory.  If we map a Banach onto its unit ball, then we define a functor from the category of Banach spaces (with linear contractions as morphisms) into that of *pointed metric spaces* with base-point preserving Lipschitz functions, as above, then what we have constructed is just an adjoint functor.  That is, the Arens-Eells space can be interpreted as a [Free-functor](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/free+functor) and $AE(X)$ is a [free object](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/free+object) over $X$.

This is perhaps not really a concrete construction, but it follows from the existence that the space is just the so-called free vector space over $M$ (as a pointed set), completed under a suitable norm (basically the observation of Nik Weaver above).  On the other end of the concrete-abstract spectrum, the existence of such an object (often called the free Banach space over $M$) can be deduced from the [Freyd adjoint theorem](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/adjoint+functor+theorem).

Comment: I added a tiny correction (since the free functor goes has as its sink the category of pointed metric spaces and Lipschitz maps.  Since the fact that **Met** is not complete... I think this can be a little issue.)... Otherwise thanks.  

This I did know, but since I am looking for a constructive/explicit description of $F$, sadly I can't use it.  But I very much like seeing category theory again, like the good-ol-days

Comment: Well, I meant the category of complete pointed metric spces of radius at most $1$ with base-preserving contractions as morphisms—-this does have products.  Could you be more precise about what you mean by „constructive/explicit“?  Taking the completion of the free vector space works in some simple cases. Maybe you could give more details on the situation you are interested in.

Comment: Basically, Nik's answer was exactly what I was looking for..a concrete description in terms of input and outputs.

Comment: Two comments: (1) you don't need radius 1 to do this and (2) all it means to say that $E$ is a predual of $F$ is that $E^* \cong F$, so there's no need to "turn the reasoning on its head". (*A* predual; uniqueness of the predual is a more subtle question.)

Comment: If you don‘t have a finite radius, you don‘t know that Lipschitz functions are bounded.  You can deduce results for this case by the usual device of replacing the metric by a uniformly (not Lipschitz) equvalent one.

Comment: Once you have a suitable compact topology on the ball of a Banach space, you know more than that it is a dual space—-you can reconstruct the required predual from the symmetric duality between Banach spaces and Waelbroeck spaces. It is the space of linear forms whose restrictions to the ball are continuous for the compact topology.  Of course, there is no need to turn the reasoning on its head—-the result is already proved.  Turning it on its head just gives another perspective and clarifies the situation.

Comment: The point I was trying to make is that the (originally algebraic) concept of a free object was transferred in the natural way to  a plethora of  topological versions—-free topological groups, free locally convex spaces ... over a topological space (metric space, uniform space, differentiable manifold, complex manifold) around the middle of the last century.The underlying principle was always the same.  You embed your space into a suitable tvs by providing the free vector space with a corresponding structure, then taking the completion which then has a characteristic universal property.

Comment: There are countless examples of this ( topological spaces into spaces of measures, metric spaces into free Banach spaces, uniform spaces into uniform measures manifolds into distributions, complex manifolds into analytic functionals,...) and the principle is always the same—-you basically construct an adjoint to a forgetful functor.  Of course, you don‘t have to do it or think of it in this way—-most people probably wouldn‘t.  However, a small minority is of the opinion that so doing sheds some light on the subject.  In this sense, it is „folklore“.

Comment: @user131781 I made a follow up post based on your answer here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/342925/reference-request-for-co-free-constructions?noredirect=1#comment857239_342925